# Auto Scrolling of Text

Tags: apache-flex

I'm having trouble figuring out how I should go about making an auto scroll functionality for a text area in Flex.

What I have is a text area that loads text from an XML file at startup, and displays it in a text area. There is also an audio track that is plays along with the text. As the words from the audio file is read out, the corresponding word in the text area is highlighted red. What I want to happen is that if the highlighted word is below the visible range of the text area I want to scroll the scroll bar to adjust accordingly to the selection.

Please Help Me...

Answer (score 0):

flash.text.TextLineMetrics can be used to measure the area text takes up within a specific component.

For example:

```
var lineMetrics : TextLineMetrics = theUiComponent.measureText(textToMeasure);
var textWidth : int = lineMetrics.width;
var textHeight : int = lineMetrics.height;
```

So you could compare the TextLineMetrics size against the area of your text box.  You then have various options for moving through the scripted text as you can measure the size of a section or the entire script.